# Laravel not logging an array into log file

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to log some arrays into laravel.log file, I am trying to do so like this:

```
Log::info('Post: ' . $postSlug . ' with the post ID: ' . $postID .
 print_r($linkMatches[0], TRUE));
```

But, nothing gets logged, but if I do `dd($linkMatches[0]);` then I get back an array:

```
array:1 [
  0 => "'https://hivnorge.no/Se-hva-vi-gjoer/Underartikler/Positive-women'"
]
```

Why do I get back an array when I do dd, but can't log it into laravel.log file?

**UPDATE**

For some reason, it started working all of a sudden, no change in the code or anything else, but now it logs everything.

Comment: Have you given the read write permission to laravel/logs folder ?

Comment: yes, I logged already other things, but this just won't work

Answer (score 1):

i think the issue is print_r tag, in doc [Laravel Log doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors)

```
Log::info('User failed to login.', ['id' => $user->id]);
```

instead of appending print_r you can pass it as param it solve your problem